# PHP change the date to Y-m-d H:i

Tags: php, datetime

### What I Require

How can I convert `2013-07-26T10:00:00.000+05:30` to **Y-m-d H:i:s** format.

I need to get 2013-07-26 10:00:00 from this.

.

### What I Tried

```
 $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601,2013-07-26T10:00:00.000+05:30);
 echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

AND

```
 $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, srtotime(2013-07-26T10:00:00.000+05:30));
 echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**Note:** *The date was obtained from google calendar's event start and end date.*

Comment: before downvoting please say whats wrong so that i can better my question

Comment: "Include attempted solutions, **why they didn't work**, and the expected results."

Comment: Why u're using "strtotime"? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-07-26T10:00:00.000+05:30');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: I do apologise, my interpreter was throwing a fit. I'll remove that comment.

Comment: No problems..:-) Mistakes can happen..

Answer (score 2):

The second argument for createFromFormat should be the string representing the time, not a timestamp. Try removing strtotime and passing in the string directly.

Alternatively you could do:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2013-07-26T10:00:00.000+05:30'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$datetime="2013-07-26T10:00:00.000+05:30";
$time=strtotime($datetime);
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$time);
```